# How t change the color of column data in table with twig?

Tags: php, twig

```
{% for item in items %}
            <tr>
                <td >
                    {{item.generated_on| date('d M, Y')| default("")}}
                </td>

                <td>
                    {{item.number}}
                </td>

                <td>
                    <ul>
                        {% for detail in item.details %}
                            <li>
                                {{detail.label}}
                            </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </td>
            <tr>
```

i want to change the color of the details.label field and its style also.
details is a object with consist of label and some other fields.
thanks in advance

Comment: Please print the actual rendered output of `detail.label`.

Comment: details.label is text

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for detail in item.details %}
    <li>
        <span class="colored-label"> {{detail.label}} </span>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

And then give style to colored-label class in css.

```
.colored-label {
    color: #ccc;
    /* other styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twig isi Beck End template, it barely have no relation with `css`. Things that you can do to styling the html is just view source of your html on browser and create css file according to it.

or, if you are in control to change `detail.label`, you can change the html structure of it.